# Github get notified when changes on file?

Tags: python, github-api, github-actions

Is it possible to get a Messagebox when a file has been edited on GitHub?
I don't know how I can use GitHub API to get the right information without downloading the file.

I would write in python if possible.

Comment: You would need to add a GitHub Action to your repository that triggers every time the repository is pushed to. In this action, run a script to send an email or something to yourself saying that the Repository was updated.

Comment: Will have a look if i can get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a workflow that triggers for any `push event` and executes a python script `run.py` located at the Github repository `/root` directory (which required the `requests` dependency to works).

```
name: Python Script Workflow triggered on Push

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Checkout the repository content to github runner.

      - name: Setup Python Version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8 # Install the python version needed

      - name: Install Python dependencies
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip requests

      - name: Execute Python script # Run the run.py to get the latest data
        run: python run.py
```

In your case, the python script could send a notification to anyone you want, or event extract other useful datas if needed.